# Play Introduction video before loading the full site wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I am trying to load introduction video before the site loads.Is there any plugin or any other way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many plugin [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-splash-page/screenshots/) may be help you

Comment: Here is a complete guide how you can do it manually [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-make-a-splash-page-with-wordpress--wp-22971)

Comment: Thanks for the help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-splash-page/)

WP Splash Page is a useful plugin if you wish a splash page in your WordPress site. In a easy way you can set up the plugin by choosing the text color or the background image among other things. It also provides you with some important features like age validation. Bots can't see the splash page. Instead, they go directly to the original page. By this way you won't lose ranking and visibility in search engines.

Comment: yes this plugin will play video

Comment: This can play you tube video not Flash video.. Is there any plugin to play flash as well

Comment: you can add the flash as page content

Comment: This plugin (WP Splash Page) has been closed as of October 23, 2019 and is not available for download. Reason: Guideline Violation.